# Change position of objects inside an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component which has a useState that contains the information i want to display and the images.

```
  const [images, setImages] = useState(
        [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "img": Volleyball,
                "text": ' Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero ut dolorem dolore modi esse reprehenderit assumenda error aut ducimus, aliquam repudiandae aliquid deserunt voluptatum placeat fugit explicabo dignissimos cum tempore.'
            },
            {
                "index": 1,
                'img': Gaming,
                "text": ' Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero ut dolorem dolore modi esse reprehenderit assumenda error aut ducimus, aliquam repudiandae aliquid deserunt voluptatum placeat fugit explicabo dignissimos cum tempore.'
            },
            {
                'index': 2,
                'img': Coding,
                "text": ' Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero ut dolorem dolore modi esse reprehenderit assumenda error aut ducimus, aliquam repudiandae aliquid deserunt voluptatum placeat fugit explicabo dignissimos cum tempore.'
            }
        ]
    )
```

And this is the jsx that I have in the return body with a left button that prevImage function.

```
 return (
        <div className={classes.gallary}>
            <div className={classes.direction}>
                <button className={classes.leftArrow} onClick={prevImage}>Left</button>
                <button className={classes.rightArrow} >Right</button>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.images}>
                {images.map(current => {
                    return (
                        <div key={current.index}>
                            <img src={current.img} alt="" className={classes.image} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

        </div>
    );
```

Here is the prevImage function :

```
 const prevImage = () => {
        const currentImgArray = [...images];
        const sendToBack = currentImgArray.push(currentImgArray.pop());
        setImages(sendToBack)
    }
```

This is what it looks like before clicking the button and what I am trying to do is to place the first object as the last object in the array . If the function is called I get : "TypeError: images.map is not a function"

[image]

Comment: that's because array.push returns the new length of the array, and not the new array itself

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.push

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is make a slide-show, so that when u hit left on the first image, it will show the last image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, array::push returns the new length of the array, not an array. Basically you need to rotate the array left/right.

```
const prevImage = () => {
  // moves last image to front of array
  setImages(images => [images[images.length - 1], ...images.slice(0, -1)]);
};
const nextImage = () => {
  // moves first image to end of array
  setImages(images => [...images.slice(1), images[0]]);
};
```

[image: Edit rotate array]

Answer (score 1):

Array.push returns new length of the array, so `concat` function is to be use on here:

```
 const prevImage = () => {
        const currentImgArray = [...images];
        const sendToBack = currentImgArray.concat(currentImgArray.pop());
        setImages(sendToBack)
    }
```

Updated ans:

```
 const prevImage = () => {
        setImages(prevState => {const popArr = prevState.pop();
                                return prevState.concat(popArr);
         })
    }
```

Comment: That fixes the error, but my objects are still in the same position